# Can I use direct file paths to access files stored in app specific storage?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an app where I capture/download images and store them to the app specific storage using:

```
File fileToSave = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "filename");
```

Then, I save the absolute path to the file in the db using:

```
saveToDb(fileToSave.getAbsolutePath())
```

My question is, will I be able to access the file later using this absolute path?

```
File file = new File(savedAbsolutePath);
```

Is this the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will I be able to access the file later using this absolute path?

Yes, assuming the user did not delete it or something.

> Is this the best practice?

If you want the user to have some ability to access the content independently of your app, using `getExternalFilesDir()` is a fine choice.

If you do not want the user to have independent access to the content, you could use `getFilesDir()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can you please explain what do you mean by independent access?

Comment: And, will this file access using file path cause problems while targetting Android 11?

Comment: @DivijGupta: "Can you please explain what do you mean by independent access?" -- I mean being able to attempt to access the file using other tools, such as a pre-installed file manager. "will this file access using file path cause problems while targetting Android 11?" -- no, you have access to `getFilesDir()` and `getExternalFilesDir()` without problems on Android 11+. Basically, if you get the root directory from a `Context` method, it is fine for you on all relevant versions of Android. It is working with *other* directories that is a problem.